# Undefined index only at first request

Tags: php, session, cart

I have created a cart for a Font Library localhost, but whenever the user sign in for example he goes straight to 'mycart.php' it shows undefined index for `$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;` but if he clicks it next time the error won't be there. The php is working perfectly fine though. Why does this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isset()` for this on `first time` like

```
$cart=(isset($_SESSION['cart']) and $_SESSION['cart']!="") ? $_SESSION['cart'] : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigment won't cause the undefined index error. This can happen when you want to retrieve the value of `$_SESSION['cart']` which wasn't set.

The problem is when you want to use the value `$_SESSION['cart']` you should check its existance with `isset()` function.

You wrote that when he click again there's no error. It's because this variable was set and it's in the session. Check if you use `$_SESSION['cart']` before you assign it.

You can check what variables are assigned to session with `print_r($_SESSION);`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `session_start()` *before* you use `$_SESSION` variable.